# Copy class in higher level in eCognition

Tags: classification, ecognition

I use eCognition to do classification. I do segmentation and I class it in level-1. Then I do segmentation in level-2. How to copy class from level-1 and paste the class in level-2 ?
There is 'Copy image level' algorithm. I succeed to use it and the class change in level-1. But when I turn to level-2, it is still no class. I don't know how to paste in level-2.

Is there anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the 'class filter'?

Comment: I input Algorithm : copy image object level. In the Domain, I input : Level-1. Class filter : lake, bare soil, urban, unclassified. In the algorithm parameters, I input Level Name : Level-2. Copy Level : above.

Comment: To copy class from level-1, I use 'convert to sub-objects' algorithm. The parameter : Level-1. Class filter : lake, bare soil, urban, unclassified. The result is still in Level-1. The difference, either the class and unclassified are divided into any small object like in Level-2. I think it is a while solution.